# Remove an item from side bar using Applescript on Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, shell, applescript

Does anyone know how can I remove an item from favourites list on finder's sidebar using applescript, If it is not possible from applescript can we do something with shell script or terminal command on Mac OS?

Here is what I did to add it via applescript:
I opened the folder which I wanted to add to the sidebar and used a shortcut (Command+Control+t) to add it to favourites menu of finder's sidebar.

Please suggest if there is any other way to do this.

Thanks

This is how we can do it using objective-c:

LSSharedFileListRef sflRef = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems, NULL);

```
AuthorizationRef auth = NULL;
NSString *itemName = @"";
AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &auth);
LSSharedFileListSetAuthorization(sflRef, auth);

UInt32 seed;

if(sflRef){
    NSArray *list = (__bridge NSArray *)LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(sflRef, &seed);

    LSSharedFileListItemRef sflItemRef = NULL;
    for(NSObject *object in list) {
        sflItemRef = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef)object;
        CFStringRef nameRef = LSSharedFileListItemCopyDisplayName(sflItemRef);
        itemName = (__bridge NSString*)nameRef;

        NSLog(@"%@", itemName);

        if ([itemName isEqualToString:@"YourItem"]) {
            LSSharedFileListItemRemove(sflRef, sflItemRef);
            break;
        }
    }
}

CFRelease(sflRef);
```

Comment: Have you tried to tweak your applescript by doing a `cmd + drag` command in order to remove it from the sidebar ?

Comment: I do not think you can.

Comment: is there anyway using c or objective-c ?

Comment: did you find a solution? using shell or applescript?

Comment: No I could not do it using shell or applescript. I did it using Objective-C.

Comment: @Trevor I have edited my question you can do it in objective c. Thanks